# Component not rerendered redux react and react-redux-starter-kit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I m actually studying react + redux (https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) and I m having some trouble with view rerendering.

I have this action / reducer :

```
/* Action part */
export const ADD_TODO_ITEM = 'ADD_TODO_ITEM';

export function addTodoItem(value = null): Action {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODO_ITEM,
    payload: value
  }
}

export const actions = {
  addTodoItem
}

/* Reducer part */

const actionHandler = {
  [ADD_TODO_ITEM]: (state, action) => {
    state.push('New todo value')
    console.log(state);
    return state;
  }

}


const initialState = [];
export default function todoReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const reducer = actionHandler[action.type];
  return reducer ? reducer(state, action) : state;
}
```

It's a simple action / reducer that should add a new item inside of a todo list.

The todo list component looks like following :

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import TodoInput from './../TodoInput/TodoInput';

type Props = {
  todos:Array
}

export class TodoList extends React.Component <void, Props, void>{


  static propTypes = {
    todos: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };


  render(){
    let i = 0;
    return(
      <div>
      <h4>Paf</h4>
      <TodoInput/>
      <ul>
        {
          this.props.todos.map((item)=>{
            i++;
            return <li key={i}>{item}</li>
          })
        }
      </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>({
 todos: state.todos
});

export default connect((mapStateToProps), {
})(TodoList)
```

As you can see, I have a TodoInput component that only sends an action event when a button is pressed. This part works well, I can log it inside of the action / reducer file.

The fact is that my TodoList component is never rerendered, and my item are not displayed as expected.

It's more weird that in fact the list appears on the screen when I use the livereload tool to code (modifying a line in my editor makes a simple refresh on browser, and at this moment the state.todos is well rendered on the screen)

It seems that I made something bad, and I can't put a finger on it.

Can you help me ?

EDIT : Problem solved. In fact, I was using a mutating state, and it seems that redux can't detect the change on this. refers to https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/585